# Caveats in analyzing 2x2 contingency tables

Tags: contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, medicine

after reading this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1440-1681.12052 I have real troubles deciding which test is most suitable for my analysis.

The data is following: a group of patients with a phenotype was selected for a study to investigate the occurrence of certain feature X. The outcome of the study is the rate of  feature X in the population of patients with the phenotype.

However, later it was discovered that a proportion of the patients was prescreened for a feature Y, which also correlates with the phenotype. Therefore, this gives the opportunity to say something about the impact the prescreening for Y has on detecting X.

Naively I would construct a 2x2 table and use Fisher's exact test:

```
                havePhenotype  noPhenotype
ScreenedForY         N1           N2
NotScreenedForY      N3           N4
```

However, after reading the paper, I am not sure which category my problem falls into and which test should be used.

Comment: You might want to search for sensitivity and specificity (singe you work in the health field, there are other terms used in other fields).